# Is it possible to set a continuous loop with gpio.pulse()?

Tags: lua, esp8266, nodemcu

Does anyone know of a way to get ESP8266 NodeMCU **gpio.pulse** module to run in a continuous loop?

I have a requirement to continuously output two stable frequency square waves that are 180° out of phase from the ESP8266's GPIO4 & GPIO5 pins. At first glance, the **gpio.pulse()** [gpio.pulse.build()] module doc example (https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/en/modules/gpio/#gpiopulsebuild) seems to meet my requirement. Unfortunately, I can find no way to make run in a continuous loop.

```
gpio.mode(1, gpio.OUTPUT)
gpio.mode(2, gpio.OUTPUT)

pulser = gpio.pulse.build( {
  { [1] = gpio.HIGH, [2] = gpio.LOW, delay=250000 },
  { [1] = gpio.LOW, [2] = gpio.HIGH, delay=250000, loop=1, count=20, min=240000, max=260000 }
})

pulser:start(function() print ('done') end)
```

I tried using gpio.pulse:update (https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/en/modules/gpio/#gpiopulseupdate) to reset the example's step 2 "count=20" parameter before it reaches zero but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you can use count=-1 (the largest possible 32 bit unsigned integer) which will let it run for around 68 years.

For higher frequencies where 2^32 repetitions are not satisfactory, then you can nest the loops:

```
pulser = gpio.pulse.build( {
  { [1] = gpio.HIGH, [2] = gpio.LOW, delay=250000 },
  { [1] = gpio.LOW, [2] = gpio.HIGH, delay=250000, loop=1, count=20, min=240000, max=260000 },
  { loop=1, count=20 }
})
```

This will run for 20 * 20 pulses before terminating.